# How to output golang http json body to website page using html/javascript/jquery

Tags: html, http, go, get

I've got a Golang Website where I want to display 'scores' from my UWP Game using SQLite's Mobile App Quickstart's API called SwaggerUI. I am getting the scores by doing a HTTP GET request. The problem is that the scores output to the Golang console in JSON Format. I want to display the scores onto the actual website. How could I call my golang function in the Frontend in order to do this? The frontend is written in HTML/Javascript/JQuery.

This is my Golang Function that does the HTTP Request to SwaggerUI and outputs to the Golang Console:

```
func scoresPage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

//Connecting to SwaggerUI API to get Scores from Azure for UWP Application

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", os.ExpandEnv("https://brainworksappservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$select=score"), nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
//You have to specify these headers
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
//If you do not specify what version your API is, you cannot receive the JSON
req.Header.Set("Zumo-Api-Version", "2.0.0")

//Do the request
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
//Error if the request cannot be done
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

//You need to close the Body everytime, as if you don't you could leak information
defer resp.Body.Close()

//Read all of the information from the body
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

//Error if the info cannot be read
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

//Write the JSON to the standard output (the Console)
_, err = os.Stdout.Write(body)
//Error if the info cannot be output to the console
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
 }

http.ServeFile(res, req, "Scores.html")
} `
```

This is the main Function which serves up the website and handles the scores page:

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/scores", scoresPage)

//serve on the port 8000 forever
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: You can use Go's [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package to render the scores inside the `Scores.html` page.

Comment: Hi mkopriva. I'm very new to Golang, only started learning it in college this semester so I'm unfamiliar with the html/template package and how it would integrate with JSON. Is there any particular tutorials you've heard of that could get me started?

Comment: At that point you wouldn't be working with JSON, you'd be working with structured data in Go; the template package doesn't provide a way to use JSON directly, you'd umarshal the JSON to something (struct, map, whatever) and then pass that to your template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you don't want to dump the json as is onto you page but instead format it in some way with html and css, then you could first decode the returned body into a slice of structs that mirror the structure of your json. For example like this:

```
type Score struct {
    Id        string    `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
    Version   string    `json:"version"`
    Deleted   bool      `json:"deleted"`
    Text      string    `json:"text"`
    Complete  bool      `json:"complete"`
    Score     string    `json:"score"`
}

scores := []*Score{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &scores); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(scores[0])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/m_ySdZulqy

After you've decoded the json you can use Go's template package to loop over the scores and format them as you wish. While you should use the [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package for rendering html you should check out [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for the documentation on how to actually program the templates, they have the same interface.

Here's a quick example: https://play.golang.org/p/EYfV-TzoA0

In that example I'm using the template package to parse a string (`scoresPage`) and output the result to stdout, but you can just as easily parse your `Scores.html` file with [ParseFiles](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) and return the output in the http response by passing the `res http.ResponseWriter` instead of `os.Stdout` as the first argument to [template.Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute).

Comment: Hi. I've been looking at the code and I've gotten the HTML to output like so: https://postimg.org/image/4kzd34ntf/ Thank you very much for that help. I get the concept of the HTML being output into the console, but I'm not sure how ParseFiles would work to output this HTML onto the website? Also, seeing as the values are output in HTML and manually added into the struct, this would make the data static. If I played my game and a new score was added to the database, would I have to manually input that score into the JSON struct?

Comment: `ParseFiles` parses your html files and returns a template (`*template.Template`), that's it, nothing more, `ParseFiles` does not ouput the contents of those files to stdout or to your website. For that, you will need to use the returned **template**, to be more precise, the template's `Execute` method. If you look at [Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute)'s documentation you can see that the first argument is of type `io.Writer`, an interface type, which is already satisfied by `http.ResponseWriter`, the first argument of your `scoresPage` function, right?

Comment: So that means, that when you pass **res** (`http.ResponseWriter`) to the template's `Execute` method, the contents of the template will be written "to your website" using the `http.ResponseWriter`... That's all you need to do to output your html files to you website.

Comment: The data will only be static if the data at "https://brainworksappservice.azurewebsites.net" is static as well. Your `scoresPage` function is making a request to `brainworksappservice` to get the data, and whatever data is returned, whether static or dynamic, that data will be rendered on your website by the template. Btw you can also "cache" your template by parsing the files only once, someplace outsite of the `scoresPages` function and then call `Execute` any number of times, with new data, and it will render that new data correctly. Let me know if something still doesn't make sense.

Comment: But if I try to pass res to the execute method I get an error: [link] https://postimg.org/image/72ydgaf1n/ The error is that res is undefined. How do I parsefiles exactly? Am I parsing the Scores.HTML where I want the data to be output? Oh I get what you mean there, the data on the database isn't static so that should clear up that part of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I used `res` because the first line in your initial example code used `res` as the name of its first argument the `http.ResponseWriter`. Here's the first line from your example `func scoresPage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {` inside this function `res` cannot be undefined... Can you screenshot your whole function?

Comment: I'm doing all of the outputting within main so that might be why it's undefined. I'll try to put my data into the scoresPage function but that usually errors out. I'll screenshot it when I have that done.

Comment: This is defined outside Main [link] (https://postimg.org/image/oan7crlrf/) And then within main: (Split into two images because it all wouldn't fit) [link] (https://postimg.org/image/rd4c43xm3/) and [link] (https://postimg.org/image/jf82937bh/)

Comment: Here's how your `scoresPage` function could look like: https://play.golang.org/p/sKkG3XsOH3. Updated version with the template string instead of the Scores.html file: https://play.golang.org/p/3lOQQNvUtU

Comment: Everything compiles properly but as soon as I try to navigate to the Scores.html page I get the following error:  [link] (https://postimg.org/image/ey605rbft/) . I get no errors in the console though. This is what my code looks like now: [link] (https://play.golang.org/p/1tQyGGrRk9) . Am I supposed to have something on the Scores.html page? The Scores.html looks like this: [link] (https://play.golang.org/p/uyX7FRuCMC) (I shouldn't have html in the GO playground but it's just for sharing purposes)

Comment: The error didn't show straight away but it was the fact that I had declared the 'Id' wrong in the html template. Now when I run the website I get some data back on the Scores.html page! [link] (https://postimg.org/image/t298ol3kf/) Is there any way to get rid of the scores that are blank? If not its fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah good to hear that it works, you can avoid empty scores by checking whether they are present, with an {{if ...}} action, either by checking the .Id or .Score, etc. it's up to you. https://play.golang.org/p/tHb9EGY38l

Comment: Thank you, great help. I handled the scores being blank on the game side with an if statement in C#. The game doesn't allow blanks anymore. My Scores look like this now with a bit of tidying up. I put them into a table on the website. https://postimg.org/image/yzd0ib505/